# Degenesis: Original rules vs Rebirth rules

Tags: balance, edition-comparison, degenesis

I have played the original Degenesis (so far only available in German) and while I absolutely *love* the setting and the atmosphere (not least the illustrations by Djurdjevic) I have always hated the rules.

It has been a while so I might not remember everything 100% correctly, but essentially my criticism boils down to this:

- Characters starting out pretty weak
- This lead our group to min-maxing
- Min/maxing in turn is really easy through the stacking bonuses of Culture, Concept and Cult
- While at the same time *regular* character development/generation was prohibitively expensive due to exponential point costs for higher skills.

> Example:
>   Having Culture/Concept and Cult with stacking skill bonus is *very* powerful compared to having to spend points to raise the skill from x to x+1, then to x+2, then to x+3.

I [read](http://www.rpg.net/reviews/archive/16/16551.phtml) that the Degenesis: Rebirth edition comes with a reworked rule system.

- **Does someone already have experience with the new rule system and can compare it to the old Degenesis rules?**

Have the above mentioned balancing issues been addressed?

Answer (score 3):

The original Degenesis is available in English, sadly it is very hard to find as it is no longer being published. It was licensed under the Creative Commons, however, though it's difficult to find it despite this. I have a copy somewhere, but I haven't seen it in ages.

### What Changed

Rebirth's system is basically entirely redone from the original. Whereas the original had a sliding scale system that I don't remember entirely well, the new version uses a d6-based success system, with player dice pools ranging from 1 to 12 dice. Any result of 4+ is a success, and a result of 6 has special benefits depending on context.

The character creation system is much different now; players allocate attributes and skills with points, but the maximum values during character creation are limited to those permitted by their Cult, Culture, and Concept. There are fewer skills, an additional attribute (Instinct), and the general consensus is that the system has just improved greatly overall.

This still allows for some min-maxing, but there's much less of it. In addition, even if a character attempts to maximize a skill or attribute, they will likely still have points left over and not be quite so incredibly inept across the board. The rank system has been greatly overhauled and most Cults have between a half dozen to over a dozen ranks, many of which run along branching trees.

There are some perceived power differences between the Cults, like the Hellvetics having a full combat kit from character creation while, say, an Anabaptist may get a sword. The balance is largely narrative; Hellvetics and Scourgers may have good gear, but they're not going to have the social abilities an Apocalyptic has.

Comment: I love how the Hellvetics are set up. They get incredibly powerful rifles, but an allowance of some 5 rounds *per month*, iirc. And they have to report the use of every single round to the quartermaster. Makes you think twice before pulling the trigger. :)

Comment: Btw, I also went out and got me one of the nice and shiny new versions. So far I mainly focused on the fluff & kults though (as you I love the new rank system), and I don't have any play experience with the new system yet.

Comment: The irony with the Hellvetics is the fact that they insist on using their really expensive 5.56mm ammunition. They can fire buckshot from the Trailblazer, which would actually be cost-effective (and the best shotgun in the core rulebook), but they really like bullets that cost a week's wages.